# SQL Join on 2 Tables

Tags: sql, join, union

i've been trying to build this query. hoping someone can help.
I have 2 tables.

1 table contains

```
Code | name | Value | Period  
1      name1   1      2010  
2      name2   2      2010
```

table 2 contains

```
code | name |  
 1    name1  
 2    name2  
 3    name3  
 4    name4
```

what i want to be displayed is

```
1 name1 1  
2 namw2 2   
3 name3 0  
4 name4 0
```

In some instances table 1 may have a value for all name variables in table 2
but where there are only 1,2,3 names i want it to display the other one but with a value of 0 or blank.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question and check the fieldnames? Is it really `1 name 1` or it is just `name 1` and you added the field id?

Comment: What all have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Join / Union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735382/sql-join-union)

Comment: This is the same question you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735382/sql-join-union), but with more generic names for your tables and columns.  Next time, you should edit the original question with new information, rather than posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
    T2.*, 
    isnull(T1.code, 0) as code -- or value
from 
    table2 T2 
    left outer join table1 T1 on T1.name = T2.name
```

You can replace `isnull(T1.code, 0) as code` with `isnull(T1.value, 0) as value`. I'm not sure what you're after ...